# How To Extract Column Names Which were in XML File and Map them with txt File In ADF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have one dataset I.e., iqvia I need to extract the data from zip, inside zip I got many txt files and one xml which has columns in it I need to map those columns with txt file

I tried to prepare xml script in synapse ntbk but none works

Answer (score 0):

First unzip the above zip file to a folder using one copy activity and then convert that xml file to txt file in with the required columns.

For that use another copy activity.

**This is my sample source xml:**

[image]

Give this in source of the copy activity.
In the sink give a text file.

And you can use advance editor in the mapping. If you want, you can also specify a dynamic content here.

[image]

Result in the text file with columns.

[image]